# how to run multiple instance of a matlab script from terminal?

Tags: matlab, terminal

I aim to run same matlab script with multiple instance from terminal Is it possible to do that with matlab? İf it is how can I do it?

Comment: In which operating system?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2081-how-to-execute-two-matlab-scripts-simultaneously) may help.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux use `&` to not wait for the end of the subprocess.

```
n = 5;

for i=1:n
    system('matlab -desktop -r ls &');
end
```

Replace `ls` with the name of the function you wish to run.

`system`, `unix` and `dos` commands are interchangeable.